# Most pythonic way to determine lowest count

Tags: python, iteration

I find myself wanting to keep a lowest/largest count when iterating through dictionaries.

For example:

```
d = {
    'Bob': 2000,
    'Larry': 6000,
    'Mary': 5
}

lowest_value = 1000000
list_of_keys = []

for key, value in d.items():
    if value > 100:
        list_of_keys.append(key)
        if value < lowest_value:
            lowest_value = value
```

Rather than setting my `lowest_value` to a number that will certainly be greater than the first `if value < lowest_value:`, is there a nicer way of doing this?

For `largest_count` I can usually just use 0 or -1.

Comment: @StephenRauch I mean setting `lowest_value` initially. You don't have value then

Comment: Or do you mean `max(list(d.values()))` ? I guess that could work

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) or [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) like:

#### Code:

```
min(d.values())
```

#### Test Code:

```
d = {
    'Bob': 2000,
    'Larry': 6000,
    'Mary': 5
}
print(min(d.values()))
```

#### Results:

```
5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `from math import inf` and use `inf` rather than some ad-hoc number. Ints compare against floats just fine in Python.

Comment: There is also `float('inf')`

Answer (score 2):

Python's builtin `min` can take an iterable. You can also put the `> 100` filter in a genexpr. Python dicts can also return an iterable of values only, since you dont' care about the keys.

```
lowest_value = min(value for value in d.values() if value > 100)
```

You can get the list of keys in a list comp separately.

```
list_of_keys = [key for key, value in d.items() if value > 100]
```

This iterates twice, but that's OK unless your dict is really large (in which case, consider using pandas dataframes instead.)

To avoid duplicating the filter step, you can use a dict comp first.

```
d2 = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v > 100}
lowest_value = min(d2.values())
list_of_keys = list(d2.keys())
```

Comment: You can also avoid the filtering step with `list_of_keys = [...]; lowest_value = d[min(list_of_keys, key=d.get)]`. BTW: your one-liner is the slowest approach.

Comment: Or even `lowest_value = min(map(d.get, list_of_keys))`

Answer (score -1):

The one-liner.

```
ks, low = [f(i) for f, i in zip([list, min], zip(*((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v>100)))]
```